# How to add a new word to keyboard by backspacing and clicking on its suggestion?

Tags: keyboard, text-input

It used to be that if I were to type a new word, like `Androidenthusiast`, it would suggest other words. I wouldn't select any, press space, backspace, and then it was there as a suggestion. If I clicked on it, it would say "Click again to save", and so I did and so it did. But as of late, it has stopped doing that.

I can't find the settings in `Language / input` > `Keyboards` anywhere. Can't remember when its behaviour changed. Nexus 5, running Android 5.1.

Comment: As @Andy356 suggests, this change may have happened with the recent update to the Google Keyboard (Version 4.1.22123.2053724 - 6 Jul 2015)? I have not installed this update yet (still on Version 4.0.21203.1613964) and I still have the functionality you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is gone. It used to be that it just wouldn't show up for those words which were already in your personal dictionary. Now it doesn't appear for any word whatsoever.

It was probably a recent update to the Google Keyboard app which broke this functionality. The Google Keyboard app updates for everyone so it wouldn't matter that my Nexus 5 is running Android 5.0 and yours is on 5.1, everyone got the bad end of the deal.

Comment: Jesus. Any chance to downgrade?

Comment: @Mave Have you tried to uninstall Google Keyboard updates?

Comment: Definitely. You could head over to any number of websites that host apks. Like Apkmirror. Type in 'google keyboard' and it'll give you an entire list of versions. I don't know which update broke functionality, so you'll have to try some out. Sorry about that...

Comment: Cheers! Downgraded to version of start of June, no joy. Will look into older versions.

Comment: @Mave Make sure you don't accidentally update it again through play store :P